# Read link from txt file

Tags: php

this code not display title when i get link from txt file

```
<?php
function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;

    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res) 
        return null; 

    // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;
}

$file = fopen("link.txt","r");
$lien = fgets($file);
fclose($file);

print page_title($lien);

?>
```

this code not display title when i get link from txt file

blank screen

my link.txt countains :

http://google.com

Comment: `$lien fgets($file);` is a typo?

Comment: You're missing `=` in `$lien fgets($file)`

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get an error? A blank screen? The wrong information? Some of the right information? Too much? Too little?

Comment: The string returned by `fgets()` has a newline at the end. You should probably trim it.

Comment: i get a blank screen

Comment: blank screen usually means you turned PHP error reporting off

Comment: You should be receiving two warnings, having [**error reporting set/on**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: This could be a clue: _'No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\postlink.php '_ The file you're trying to open either doesn't exists, or isn't where you say it is.

Comment: I corrected but nothing shows title page blank screen

Comment: Put this 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  right after your opening `<?php` tag. You will see the errors.

Comment: Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code i get the word "Google" displayed on my screen. So i have to think that your code is doing what you want but that there is some other, perhaps host-specific, problem here.

OK I just broke it by putting a CR in the text file after the URL and I fixed it by changing

```
$lien = fgets($file);
```

to

```
$lien = trim(fgets($file));
```

Comment: I don't know which setting you have on your host to allow it, but it doesn't let me access is.

Comment: @Fred--Just for kicks I added error_reporting(E_ALL) . . . and it still runs properly with no errors.

Comment: My server throws back `Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in...` so am sure it's got something to do with a certain server setting, but can't remember which one it is.

Comment: However, if I add `$url = "http://google.com";` under `function page_title($url) {` it runs; bizarro.

Comment: OK I just broke it by putting a CR in the text file after the URL and I fixed it by changing$lien = fgets($file);  to   $lien = trim(fgets($file));   I think that explains why when you avoid the file read it works.

Comment: Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:

Comment: @BigScar Add that in your answer, because that worked for me. However, my file did have a CR, I always do ;-) and it should work for the OP also.

Comment: @Naruto I got the same error you did until i did this:   
 
$lien = trim(fgets($file));